# How can I define a function that takes `Integer` values, borrows, and primitive integers as input without unnecessary conversion?

Tags: rust, traits

I have an arbitrary precision `Integer` type. I have FFI bindings that require only a pointer to these integers as input. I would like to define a function that can take primitive signed/unsigned integer types as well as their borrows, and `Integer`/`&Integer` as input. Primitive integers will be converted to `Integer`, and either `Integer` or `&Integer` can be converted to a pointer for use with the FFI.

How can I define a function that takes all of these inputs without unnecessary conversion? For example, I initially defined the function like this:

```
pub fn test<T: Into<Integer>>(T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Then if we implement `From<x> for Integer` for all primitive integer types `x` as well as `From<&Integer> for Integer`, this function will accept all of the types I want. However, converting `&Integer` to `Integer` obviously requires an additional allocation (`Integer` is heap allocated) so this conversion is not ideal.

Alternatively, I can define a function like:

```
pub fn test<T: AsRef<Integer>>(x: T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

which avoids converting borrows to values, so avoids additional heap allocation. However, this function does not accept primitive integer types and `AsRef` cannot be implemented for them in this way (otherwise you will have functions returning references to values they own).

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds? Accepting primitive integers which are converted to `Integer` without converting borrows (`&Integer`)?

Please let me know if an MWE would be helpful or if the question is unclear.

Comment: Generally, create a trait and implement it for your types. What methods does `test()` need to call?

Comment: I can't really restrict the methods `test` might call. This is more or less a general purpose CAS. I think what you suggest is the best way forward though. I will probably create traits for the different number types. I was avoiding it since the `num_traits` crate wasn't quite general enough and if I use traits for this I wanted to use a well-known crate, but it seems I will have no choice but to expand on the traits they provide. @ChayimFriedman